# What type of weed is this

Tags: weed-control, weeds

I am a new homeowner in Dallas. and I am mowing my lawn for the first time. I have bermuda grass in my lawn.

In between, especially in the area of bare spots, I see cluster of grass blades, connected to one root system.

I am having hard time understanding if it is a weed or some other grass type. Looking online, looks like it could be crabgrass or bluegrass. Can anyone here see the picture attached an help me know what it is

[image]

[image]